# Sequence doesnot exist error while accessing sequence from another schema of same DB

Tags: java, oracle, ejb, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have two schemas in my DB. 
One is "admin" schema and another is "user" schema.

I have created a sequence in "admin" schema. My weblogic ejb application reads the DB details like data-source name, table name, columns, schema name from weblogic-cmp-jar.xml file. In the data-source name I gave the DS for "user" schema. I need my application to read the DB properties correctly and populate the ejb bean.

However, I am getting the below error (Sequence doesn't exist) while updating a record in the DB:

```
> WARN - com.abc.xyz.SomeHandlerEJB_vhem4v_Impl - [ACTIVE]
> ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
> - update
>         javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: EJB Exception:
>         at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EJBRuntimeUtils.asTxRollbackLocalException(EJBRuntimeUtils.java:151)
>         at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseLocalObject.handleSystemException(BaseLocalObject.java:471)
>         at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.BaseEJBLocalHome.handleSystemException(BaseEJBLocalHome.java:102)
>         at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EntityEJBLocalHome.create(EntityEJBLocalHome.java:171)
>         at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.EntityEJBLocalHome.create(EntityEJBLocalHome.java:133)
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

        at weblogic.ejb.container.cmp.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceManager.execGenKeyQuery(RDBMSPersistenceManager.java:4434)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.cmp.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceManager.getNextGenKeyPreFetch(RDBMSPersistenceManager.java:4356)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.cmp.rdbms.RDBMSPersistenceManager.getNextSequenceKey(RDBMSPersistenceManager.java:4309)
        at
```

Here is my content of weblogic-cmp-jar.xml file :

```
    <weblogic-rdbms-bean>
        <ejb-name>MyEJB</ejb-name>
        <data-source-name>jdbc/MyDS</data-source-name>
        <table-map>
            <table-name>my_table</table-name>
            <field-map>
                <cmp-field>messageId</cmp-field>
                <dbms-column>messageId</dbms-column>
            </field-map>
            ----------
            ----------
        </table-map>
        <automatic-key-generation>
            <generator-type>Oracle</generator-type>
            <generator-name>SEQ_MYSEQNAME</generator-name>
            <key-cache-size>1</key-cache-size>
        </automatic-key-generation>
    </weblogic-rdbms-bean>
```

Below is the behavior I have observed :

```
    <generator-name>SEQ_MYSEQNAME</generator-name>        // does not work
    <generator-name>ADMIN.SEQ_MYSEQNAME</generator-name>  // works fine
```

In DB from --user-- schema if I get the below result  :

```
    select * from user_sequences // It does not show anything.
    select * from ALL_SEQUENCES  // It displays the sequence names.
```

**I want to use only the sequence name without the sequence owner.**

I am using the below s/w stack :

1. Weblogic 12c
2. Oracle DB 12g
3. Java 1.8

Comment: What about creating synonyms in the user schema that would point to the sequence in the admin schema? is that allowed in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case , the SYNONYM `SEQ_MYSEQNAME FOR "ADMIN"."SEQ_MYSEQNAME"`  was already created in DB. We have deleted the existing SYNONYM and re-created the same SYNONYM again with proper permissions. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I feel adding below `SYNONYM` in your USER Schema would get the job done.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE SYNONYM SEQ_MYSEQNAME FOR "ADMIN"."SEQ_MYSEQNAME";
```

Apart from this addition in User Schema, no other change would be required in Weblogic / Application Configurations.

Comment: synonym already been created in user schema :

CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM "USER"."USER_DEF_SEQ" FOR "ADMIN"."SEQ_MYSEQNAME";

Comment: EDITONABLE has not been used.. I dont know that.

Comment: I am using PRIVATE synonym not global/public.